# Xamarin keeps creating SwiftSupport folder

Tags: swift, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am building a release version of a Xamarin app which has no Swift dependencies.

When I try to archive the project for publishing I keep finding the "SwiftSupport" folder with an empty "iphoneos" sub-folder.

Normally I expect the "SwiftSupport" folder to not be created if the project doesn't include any dylib, and that's the case if I create a new blank Xamarin project.

So my question is. How can I disable the creation of the "SwiftSupport" folder?

I looked pretty much everywhere but the only "answer" that I get is simply "delete that folder" and that doesn't fit the requirements of my question:

- **What causes the creation of the SwiftSupport folder?**
- **How to prevent the creation of the SwiftSupport folder in a Xamarin use case where there are no swift libraries involved (Like the default Xamarin project)**

Comment: Seems like this is a default behavior/design , to avoid it we can disable `Embedded Content Contains Swift Code` settings in `Xcode` ,but I can't find how we do in Visual Studio . HOWEVER, it does not matter how big your IPA file is (if that's your concern) because Apple removes the folders on processing via iTunes connect.

Comment: It's not a size issue, It's correlated to the validation step that would fail if the folder is present but empty.
The task should be handled by a CI pipeline that would give the well known "Invalid Swift Support" error.

The strange part is that It's not happening with a blank project. The build package will be create as expected without the SwiftSupport folder.

Comment: Does the folder generate every time or just once when archiving?

Comment: It happens every time